# Github Desktop refusing to work after changing username

Tags: github, github-desktop

I changed my username on github and reconfigured git in Github Dektop but it doesn't work.
Help.

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3UZ9.png)

[image]

Comment: Please provide more detail about your issue - what operating system are you on, does the account you're attempting to access use Two-Factor Authentication, etc?

Comment: Windows and no.

Comment: This kind of issues usually get produced on windows . I used to use it long back but the amount of time it used to consume to debug errors of this kind reduced my productivity . I moved to Ubuntu it's developer friendly and now it's easy going .

Answer (score 1):

There are some git cookies files in your system which are still getting the old files . You can find them in .git folder and are generally hidden . Delete it . Also check if you have _netrc file in your system . You need to save a token here with respect to the new I'd .